# How to show that this equation has 2 real valued solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The real-valued solutions of  the equation $|dy/dx|+|y|+a=0$ are needed to be found in different cases for $a$. So I took the case 1st when $a=0$ then $y(x)=0$ is the only real-valued function and then I took the case 2nd when $a>0$ then there is no real-valued function. But I could not find the number of the solution when $a<0$.
In the third case, for the solution to be real-valued, $y$ should be lesser than $a$ so I am wondering; can there be two real-valued functions be determined; $y(x)=0$ and $|y|<a$.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Dispensing of the absolute values gives us four possibilities

$$dy/dx,y\geq 0$$
$$dy/dx\geq 0,y<0$$
$$dy/dx<0,y\geq 0$$
$$dy/dx,y<0$$

This gives us four differential equations
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y-a$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-y-a$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y+a$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-y+a$$

This gives us solutions of
$$ce^x+a$$
$$ce^{-x}+a$$
$$ce^{x}-a$$
$$ce^{-x}-a$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.